# Массив начиная с 1

Tags: php, массивы

Храню данные в .dat файле, потом вывожу так:

```
$data = file('file.dat');
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' '.$value;
}
```

Выводит `0 test2 1 test2 2 test2 3 test2 4 test2`

Далее делаю проверку на наличие определенного ключа в массиве. Если ключ есть, то код выполняется и наоборот. Столкнулся с тем, что проверка ключа **0** не проходит и происходит обновление страницы.
Проверяю так:

```
if(!isset($data[0])) echo 'ошибка';
```

Если проверяю 1 или 2, например, то такого не происходит.

Comment: Ваш код работает. `if(!isset($data[0])) echo 'ошибка';` ошибки не выдает.

Comment: @Visman , `$data = file('file.dat');
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.' '.$value;
 }
 if(!isset($data[0])) echo 'error'; /* Если ID не обнаружен */
 else { /* Если ID обнаружен*/
  echo $goto;
 }`
$goto - это $_GET. У меня выходит так. Если оно равно 1 или 2, то код выполняется, а если 0, то просто обновляется страница.
Ошибки нет, да, но и не работает.

Comment: @WIGGY что Вы подразумеваете под **оно** и **что именно** у Вас не работает ?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (array_key_exists('0', $data)){
    echo 'ключ существует';
}
else{
    echo 'ключ не существует';
}
```